# Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql

In find_by_id() method the first line has this error ( Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\product.php on line 14 )

```
include_once('database.php');
class Product{
    private $database;

    public function _construct (){
        $this->database = new MySQLDatabase();
    }
    public function find_by_id($id=1){
        $result = $this->database->query("select * from product where id = $id");
        $array = $this->database->fetch_array($result);
        return $array;
    }
}
```

this is the database.php file that i have included above

```
class MySQLDatabase{
private $connection ;

public function _construct(){
    $this->open_connection();
}
public function open_connection(){
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DBNAME);
    $this->connection = $dbc;
    echo 'connection opened';
}   
public function close_connection(){
    mysqli_close($this->connection);
}
public function query($sql){
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connection,$sql);
    return $result;
}
public function fetch_array($result){
    return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}
}
```

so why this error ? please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: ALL of these `_construct` need to be replaced with `__construct` unless that's a typo on your part. **[Constructs](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.construct.php) require 2x underscores.**

Comment: You're welcome. I put in an [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20228621/1415724), to close the question properly, cheers, glad I could help.

Comment: Is this class your own construction? If so, why? This thing is just asking for [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because you're not [properly escaping your SQL parameters](http://bobby-tables.com/php). When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Avoid** use string interpolation to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALL of these `_construct` need to be replaced with `__construct` unless that's a typo on your part.

[**Constructs**](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.construct.php) require 2x underscores.

Read the manual on PHP.net's website for more information on constructs:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.construct.php**

Answer (score 0):

Your class is named "MySQLDatabase", but you are calling

```
$this->database = new Database();
```

Therefore you have not Database object and "query" is not a function. You must call the class by its name (not by its Filename), so by changing it to

```
$this->database = new MySQLDatabase();
```

your code should work.

Comment: Did you not read/see [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228256/call-to-a-member-function-query-on-a-non-object#comment30166885_20228256) ? @user1561046 I will bet you that's what the problem is, or "part" of it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 
  _construct()
```

to

```
 
  __construct()
```

That should resolve your issue because PHP calls **__construct()** when creating an object. 
 
Hope this helps.